# How to make jquery tab non editable/readonly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

**Is there any way to make content of particular tab non editable or read only** .Is there any short hand syntax like for disabling the tab `$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", true );` for edit option. I just gone through the [Doumentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/), but did not find any option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent user from entering tab completely you can simply add `display:none` to tab in question. But if you want it to be still visible and selectable (tab, not it's contents), you will have to handle form controls in it separately. JQuery UI is agnostic of contents of your tabs.

Comment: I need tab should be visible and selectable but its content should be read only.

Comment: Then you will have to deal with form elements manually, tabs have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David Jashi in that tabs have nothing to do with it but here is one possible solution in which you listen for that specific tab to be clicked and disable stuff.

```
$('#disabled_stuff_tab').on('click', function(){
    //set all form fields to disabled when tab is clicked
    $('form.disabled').find('input, textarea, select').prop('disabled',true);
});

$('form.disabled').on('submit', function(e){
    //in case the script above screws up an doesn't make everything disabled
    //never allow submittal of a disabled form
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Good Luck!